# Run Excel Web Office Script when worksheet opens

Tags: office-scripts

Is it possible to invoke office script when user opens worksheet?

Thanks,
Praveen Kumar P

Comment: This is not very descriptive or helpful. Please add more details of what it is you are trying to do, what you have done and what should the final output look like.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to attach an event-based execution to the script. It is part of the investigation backlog. It'd help if you could add feature asks here: https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/274580-excel-for-the-web?category_id=143439